Salesforce Lightning doesn't use a real (native) Shadow DOM, cannot see the #shadow-root (open) in console
Some elements are under shadow dom and cannot be viewed via dev console, looking for suggestion on how to identify these elements for automation.Any suggestions on how we can identify these elements for selenium automation?
